# How to output the correct statement in a loop using python

Tags: python, python-docx

I am currently working on some python (version 3.10.4) code on PyCharm (Community Edition 2021.3.3) using the python-docx library (version 0.8.1.1), that allows to determine if text (in a Word document) formatted in the 'Normal' style contains a specific font (Times New Roman or Times New Roman and Cambria Math). When I execute the code the statements printed are not those desired.

What I mean here is that if all text (in the 'Normal' style) are in Times New Roman it should print, "Body text is in Times New Roman", while if text contains both Times New Roman and Cambria Math it should print, "Body text is Times New Roman and Cambria Math" and if text is neither all Times New Roman nor a combo of Times New Roman and Cambria Math, it should print, "Unrecognised body text font".

When I execute the code (as shown below) it prints a combination of 'Body text is in Times New Roman' and 'Unrecognised body text font' (both printed the amount of times such occurrences are present in the document). The Word document contains the following fonts: Times New Roman, Cambria Math and Arial (used only for testing purposes). So it should print "Unrecognised body text font" (as all text are not Times New Roman nor a combo of Times New Roman and Cambria Math).

```
import docx  # import the python-docx library
WordFile = docx.Document("my file directory")  # Word document file directory for python-docx to access

for paragraph in WordFile.paragraphs:
    name = []
    if 'Normal' == paragraph.style.name:
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            name.append(run.font.name)
            for i in name:
                if i == 'Times New Roman':   # checks if the elements in name = [] are 'Times New   Roman'
                    print("Body text is in Times New Roman")  # print this statement if all  elements in name = [] are 'Times New Roman'
                elif i == 'Times New Roman' and i == 'Cambria Math':  # checks if the elements in name = [] are 'Times New Roman' and 'Cambria Math'
                    print("Body text is Times New Roman and Cambria Math")  # print this if fonts in name = [] are both 'Times New Roman' and 'Cambria Math'
                else:
                    print("Unrecognised body text font")  # print this if fonts in name = [] are neither all 'Times New Roman' nor a combo of 'Times New
                    # Roman' and 'Cambria Math'
```

I believe the problem lies in the loops in which it check if all elements in the empty list name = [] are of a particular font. The print statements should only execute if all elements in the list satisfy the given conditions and only one of the statements should be printed not a combination as currently produced. But I cannot seem to be able to solve this issue. Any form of help would be appreciated. A picture of the currently produced outputs is attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this kind of functionality:

```py
# return True if both Times New Roman and Cambria Math appear in your final list
all(i in name for i in ['Times New Roman', 'Cambria Math'])
```

or maybe:

```py
# return True if *only* Times New Roman and Cambria Math appear in the final list
all(i in ['Times New Roman', 'Cambria Math'] for i in name)
```

Without understanding the rest of the logic, there appears to be other issues in the code:

- This font check should probably be deindented, so it will run only after collecting information on each paragraph (or, document?)
- It seems we are needlessly appending a font name to the list, causing duplication and slowing down your final list iteration. Is an analysis of this list ultimately needed? If not, consider a check or another data type like `set` to avoid duplication.

For now, just a simple revision of your logic to achieve the desired behavior. I implemented one of the variants of the list checks, but you can choose the one that fits your use case.

```py
import docx  # import the python-docx library

# Word document file directory for python-docx to access
WordFile = docx.Document("test1.docx")

font_names = set()
for paragraph in WordFile.paragraphs:
    if "Normal" == paragraph.style.name:
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            if run.font.name is not None and run.font.name not in font_names:
                font_names.add(run.font.name)

if {"Times New Roman", "Cambria Math"} == font_names:
    # print this if fonts in name = [] are both 'Times New Roman' and 'Cambria Math'
    print("Body text is Times New Roman and Cambria Math")
elif {"Times New Roman"} == font_names:
    # checks if the elements in name = [] are 'Times New Roman'
    # print this statement if all  elements in name = [] are 'Times New Roman'
    print("Body text has Times New Roman")
else:
    print("Unrecognised body text font")
```

Comment: Hey @dxdc thanks for the help. You code seems to work. But it does not print only one statement, but rather all those that are relevant to the document. 

Currently with my document having 'Normal' style text in Times New Roman and Cambria Math it prints "Body text is in Times New Roman" and "Body text is Times New Roman and Cambria Math", in this instance only the latter statement should be printed. Any ideas as to how this can be implemented?

Comment: @user101 I modified the code a bit for you, which I hope is the functionality that you now want. I'm not sure whether you're looking for the intersection functionality (e.g., at *least* these fonts are in the list) or whether you want this to be an exact match. I think you want the exact match solution. I've added some checks (e.g., run.font.name is not None) and ensuring we're only adding it if it already exists. I also moved the evaluation of the fonts after the paragraph so we're only evaluating it once per document.

Comment: many thanks mate. It works as required. Just a quick question for you, what do the curly brackets in the loops mean, as in how does it differ to regular brackets?

Comment: @user101 check the syntax for sets vs lists

Comment: @ dxdc got it, will check it out. 
Just another question, if I want to account for instances of 'None' (which is the default font on Word; Calibri (Body)) by printing a statement, what could I do?
I have tried with (replacing the part where it includes None): 
if run.font.name not in font_names:
                font_names.add(run.font.name)

 And then with an elif statement (just before the else):
elif {"None"} == font_name:
    print("Default font found")

But this approach prints, "Unrecognised body text font".

Comment: @user101 remove the quotes from None, it's a built in type.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, I think the easiest way to edit your current implementation would be to keep track of what fonts you identify. You could save the identified fonts in a `set` and check what's found after the loop. So something like this:

```
import docx  # import the python-docx library
WordFile = docx.Document("my file directory")  # Word document file directory for python-docx to access

font_names = set()
for paragraph in WordFile.paragraphs:
    if 'Normal' == paragraph.style.name:
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            font_name = run.font.name
            if font_name not in ('Times New Roman', 'Cambria Math'):
                font_names.add(font_name)
            else:
                font_names.add("Unrecognized")
                break
        else:
            continue
        break

if "Unrecognized" in font_names:
    print("Unrecognised body text font")
elif 'Times New Roman' in font_names:
    if len(font_names) == 2 and 'Cambria Math' in font_names:
        print("Body text is Times New Roman and Cambria Math")
    elif len(font_names) == 1:
        print("Body text is in Times New Roman")
```

I'm assuming you don't want the prints for each paragraph, and rather for the entire text. Feel free to ask any questions regarding the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Dilith Jayakody. Its seem to work as required.
Just a few question regarding the changes: what does the line if len(font_names) == 2 and 'Cambria Math' in font_names: and elif len(font_names) == 1 do in the code. Sorry I'm fairly new to python.

Comment: It Checks the no of elements in that array. @user101

Comment: But what does the 2 and 1 refer to in the lines: len(font_names) == 2, len(font_names) == 1. @mrtechroid

Comment: @user101 By `if len(font_names) == 2`, I'm checking if there are exactly two fonts in the set of fonts. (Side note: You may already know this, but in a `set`, if we add the same item twice, it doesn't create duplicates). We already know that "Times New Roman" is already in the set of fonts (because of the previous line). So if "Cambria Math" is also in the set (` and 'Cambria Math' in font_names`), then we can say that those two are the only two items in the set. Similarly, if `len(font_names) == 1`, we can say that "Times New Roman" is the only font.

Comment: Cheers @Dilith Jayakody. I understand the code much better now.

Comment: Ok so now when I have the all of of the 'Normal' style text in Times New Roman and Cambria Math, it still says '"Unrecognised body text font".  Any idea as to why this might be happening? @Dilith Jayakody

Comment: Well, you could try adding a print statement before `font_names.add("Unrecognized")` to see what font it found. So something like:

`else:
    print("Unrecognized font:", font_name)
    font_names.add("Unrecognized")`